# Cause an exception "ReadOnly controls collection" - when editing UI

Tags: c#, winforms, krypton-toolkit

I've taken over someone else's project and they have used Krypton Toolkit. When I change anything on the UI, (i.e., Add button, edit Text, add menu item), I get this exception error:

> this.kryptonHeaderGroupMain.Controls.Add(this.kryptonHeaderGroupMain.Panel);
>
> Cause an exception "ReadOnly controls collection"

..and it mucks up the Designer View.

What am I missing?

As some people recommended, I have tried it but still failed:

```
this.<kryptonControlsContainer>.Panel.Controls.Add(this.<otherControlName>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Controls` property of the `KryptonHeaderGroup` control is a custom Controls Collection (it's named [`KryptonReadOnlyControls`](https://github.com/Krypton-Suite/Standard-Toolkit/blob/a2e8a744c0e0be143e9cdcab138b60da21fb7d52/Source/Krypton%20Components/Krypton.Toolkit/General/KryptonReadOnlyControls.cs#L21)) which doesn't allow adding or removing child controls. The way `KryptonHeaderGroup` was designed is that it has a `Panel` which acts as the container for its child controls. What you need to do is as follows.

#### In design-mode:

Before adding any controls, make sure you select the panel and not the `KryptonHeaderGroup` itself. See the difference in these screenshots:

[image: Don't select the KryptonHeaderGroup itself]

[image: Select its panel instead]

#### Using code:

```
//kryptonHeaderGroup1.Controls.Add(new KryptonButton());        // Throws an exception.
kryptonHeaderGroup1.Panel.Controls.Add(new KryptonButton());    // Works fine.
```

---

**Note:** The same logic applies for other controls like `KryptonGroupBox`, `KryptonGroup`, and `KryptonSplitContainer`.